# Is a hyphen necessary when dropping the second word of the first of two open compound nouns?

Tags: hyphenation

The title is quite confusing, so here is the quote that I am unsure about:

> It was observed that the **arm- and leg movements** were...

If I understand correctly, 'arm movements' and 'leg movements' are open compound nouns. The word 'movements' is being reused, in the way that one can reuse the second part of a compound adjective; for example, "there were over- and under-fed dogs". However, since there are no hyphens used in the original compound nouns, it seems strange to me to add one.

The question: is the hyphen after 'arm' required?

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a compound, but a syntactic construction, i.e. a compound nominal. I'd write it as "... arm and leg movements".

Comment: You say it seems strange to add a hyphen. So why are you considering it?

Comment: The quote is from a piece that somebody else has written. I am wondering if they know something that I don't, or if it is just wrong.

Comment: It is just wrong. BillJ is right.

Comment: 'Arm and leg movements' arguably introduces an ambiguity, and there  are doubtless more problematic examples. 'Arm movements and leg movements' doesn't take much longer to type.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Except for the idiom "costs an arm and a leg", I don't think "arm and leg" is a thing, so I'd argue that there's not much ambiguity.